# Variable not available after using a switch statement?

Tags: java, variables, scope, switch-statement, case

So this is my homework and to me it seems to be a variable scope question. I have tried defining a global, but perhaps I was doing it incorrectly, because that did not seem to satisfy my compiler either. I am currently using SublimeText2 for my code writing but it doesn't seem to be much help. Should I be using an IDE such as Eclipse or Aptana Studio?

```
// EmployeeBonus2.java - This program calculates an employee's yearly bonus.

import javax.swing.*;

public class EmployeeBonus2
{
    public class Globals {
    public double employeeBonus;
}
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    String employeeName;
    String salaryString;
    double employeeSalary;
    String ratingString;
    int employeeRating;
    double employeeBonus;
    final double BONUS_1 = .15;
    final double BONUS_2 = .10;
    final double BONUS_3 = .06;
    final double NO_BONUS = 0.00;
    final int RATING_1 = 1;
    final int RATING_2 = 2;
    final int RATING_3 = 3;

    // This is the work done in the housekeeping() method
    // Get user input.
    employeeName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter employee's name: ");
    salaryString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter employee's yearly salary: ");
    ratingString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter employee's performance rating: ");

    // Convert Strings to int or double.
    employeeSalary = Double.parseDouble(salaryString);
    employeeRating = Integer.parseInt(ratingString);


        switch(employeeRating)
      {
        case 1: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_1);
        break;
        case 2: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_2);
        break;
        case 3: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_3);
        break;
      };


    // This is the work done in the endOfJob() method
    // Output.
    System.out.println("Employee Name " + employeeName);
    System.out.println("Employee Salary $" + employeeSalary);
    System.out.println("Employee Rating " + employeeRating);
    System.out.println("Employee Bonus $" + employeeBonus);

    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I get this error when attempting to compile.

```
EmployeeBonus2.java:54: variable employeeBonus might not have been initialized
    System.out.println("Employee Bonus $" + employeeBonus);
```

Comment: The error says that the variable is not initialized. Its always a good practice to initialize a variable with some value(may be 0)during declaration.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma Assigning an initial value will hide errors, hide the fact that there is essentially a single assignment per execution and is a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

You need a `default` case in the event that none of the `case` statements are matched.

Comment: And set the value of employeeBonus in that default block. Alternatively, you could just give employeeBonus a default value while defining it.

Comment: If you make `employeeBonus` `final` you will ensure that you assign it exactly once. No fall throughs or similar errors. Assigning an initial value will hide errors, hide the fact that there is essentially a single assignment per execution and is a bad idea.

Comment: Or, if you know the default case will never happen, just throw an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding upon Louis' answer:
Change

```
  switch(employeeRating)
  {
    case 1: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_1);
    break;
    case 2: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_2);
    break;
    case 3: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_3);
    break;
  };
```

To

```
  switch(employeeRating)
  {
    case 1: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_1);
    break;
    case 2: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_2);
    break;
    case 3: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * BONUS_3);
    break;
    default: employeeBonus = (employeeSalary * NO_BONUS);
    break;
  };
```

I kept the multiplication there to keep the calculation the same, so in the event that the concept of "no bonus" becomes "no individual bonus, but give 0.5% to everyone that doesnt otherwise have a bonus" `NO_BONUS` can be set to 0.5% and it would work.  Unlikely but that's just an example of why it's like that.  Otherwise, just set `employeeBonus` to 0, or `employeeBonus = NO_BONUS`.  Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your line#54 i.e.     `System.out.println("Employee Bonus $" + employeeBonus);` is giving a *compile time error* that *The local variable `employeeBonus` may not have been initialized*.

This could be solved by initializing the employeeBonus variable at line#18 something like this: `double employeeBonus = 0;` or else

Add a `default` case in your switch statement like this:

```
default:
    employeeBonus = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declaring a variable inside a method (Local Variable), you must initialize the Local Variable before you use the variable. In your case give a default value for employeeBonus.